# Unknown Hash Type

Tags: passwords, hash

During a CTF, I came across a certain hash type which can't be identified by various tools (hashID, crackstation, hashes.com, etc.)

The data is as so:

```
- Plaintext : abc123

- Hash : 7inmu7WsEM3erPqQT23neSWBybGgry5QSq4yXdUS+rA=
- Salt : k5mb8wfWA0qV+EVAXLOjOK7OLbC5NtPO02zEruq42+s=

- Hash (hex) : ee29e6bbb5ac10cddeacfa904f6de7792581c9b1a0af2e504aae325dd512fab0
- Salt (hex) : 93999bf307d6034a95f845405cb3a338aece2db0b936d3ced36cc4aeeab8dbeb
```

What type of format can it be in? I have tried several SHA-256 formats (salt+hash,hash+salt, etc.) but to no avail.

Comment: It can be anything. You don't know the iteration count, how the rounds are composed, if there's any padding or transformation. So it's pretty much a bruteforce.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't appear to be any of the algorithms directly supported by MDXfind, up to 100,000 iterations inclusive.